# How to make browser request new js and css files

Tags: javascript, http

I want to show some important information to the users (via banner).

So, I want to set new cookies through js. I need users browsers to request new js files and not take them from cache. And this should work in mostly all browsers. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the browser an HTML document with different URLs in the `src` attributes of the `<script>` elements.

You could add a query string if you don't want to rename a static file.

Comment: like this <script src='/script.js?t=1234'></script>
Make t to be a timestamp